# Display sprite containing images of different sizes with same size

Tags: css, css-sprites

I am using sprite image in my application. It has flag images of different size height & width. But I have to display all the flag images with same size in my grid. Currently they are displaying with different sizes

```
<div ng-repeat="i in arr">
  <img class="img-{{i.id}}" /> {{i.name}}
</div>
var arr = [{
    id: 1,
    name:: test1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name:: test2
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name:: test3
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name:: test4
  }
]
```

**CSS**

```
.img-1 {
  width: 810px;
  height: 540px;
  background: url('./../images/sprite.png') -12530px -4970px;
}

.img-2 {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 600px;
  background: url('./../images/sprite.png') -10390px -3730px;
}

.img-3 {
  width: 320px;
  height: 320px;
  background: url('./../images/sprite.png') -8780px -8030px;
}

.img-4 {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
  background: url('./../images/sprite.png') -4718px -11840px;
}
```

How to display all flags of same size height & width ?

Comment: why are they so big? a png that size is probably not worth being a sprite as surely the file size is massive, you might want to think about using an svg if they are that big.  Also if you want them the same size, why not make the sprite with them the same size to start with?

Comment: you must create a new sprite using same dimention images size

Comment: Cann't we display them in same size using CSS?

Comment: yes but you are slowing your site down by using such a massive png.  Have a google for responsive sprites, that will be the sort of thing you will need to do